# Understanding ACPI wake-up codes / DSDT (Differentiated System Description Table) of Thinkpad T430s BIOS

Tags: acpi, bios, thinkpad, sleep, dsdt

I'd like to trim wakeup events of my laptop. Could someone please explain me these 4 letter codes - which devices do they actually represent?

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

I have documented some findings as an answer below. Seems that now only IGBE and HDEF are lacking from the picture.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch. I've documented findings and guessing as an answer. Now 2 codes are lacking. Hopefully someone more more experienced knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is partial answer. From the [ACPI wakeup 4-letters code meaning?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236127/acpi-wakeup-4-letters-code-meaning) I understand the following:

```
LID  - laptop lid
EXP3 - PCI Express Root Port nr 3 - could be broadband modem in my case (not sure how to pinpoint if it is actually in slot 3)
XHCI, EHC1, EHC2 - USB controllers
```

Now guessing:

```
SLPB - sleep button :-)
```

and finally what could be IGBE and HDEF?