# Wake on lid open but don't suspend on lid close?

Tags: gnome, opensuse, suspend, acpid

I am currently running GNOME on openSUSE on my laptop, there is the setting in the GNOME tweak tool to enable suspend on lid close, which works. However, I want to do the opposite, so that the computer does not suspend on lid close, but when I open the lid, the computer will wake if it has not already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disabling suspend on lid close

The disabling of suspend on lid close is well covered on this site as well as other SE sites. Here's a list of Q&A's on that particular part of your question:

- [GNOME: disable sleep on lid close](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307497/gnome-disable-sleep-on-lid-close/307498)
- [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

#### Enabling wake on lid open

In setting up an action for when the lid opens, again this is covered in several questions:

- [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events)

The approach that I'd start with utilizes the APCI events of your hardware. With this particular approach you'd create a script that'll get triggered on the open event:

- `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`

You then need to create a file with the following content:

```
$ cat /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

And then restart the ACPI service with something like this:

```
$ service acpid restart
```

#### /etc/acpi/lid.sh

There are many versions of scripts that you can use to perform this operation. There's one [such script here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/1a3320fda5a47fdebde7/raw/87cde3f0554467a132aba3cda7ad3c5e7187571f/lid.sh.post).

The gist of this script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo close>>/tmp/screen.lid
fi
grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo open>>/tmp/screen.lid
fi
```

Within this script you'd simply need to toggle your LID or LID0 device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. Doing this toggles the LID device:

```
$ echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

So in the script above, you'd check `/proc/acpi/wakeup` to see if it's enabled or disabled. If it's disabled, then do the above `echo "LID" ...`, otherwise do nothing.

#### References

- [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events/526003#526003)
- [ACPI wakeup 4-letters code meaning?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236127/acpi-wakeup-4-letters-code-meaning)