# Debian PC not waking up after suspending to RAM

Tags: debian, suspend, acpi

When I suspend my computer to RAM, it won't wake up when I press the keys or move the mouse, or even press the power button, and I have to turn the computer off and on again. I believe the suspend works, as the power LED starts blinking instead of being constantly on. I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with my monitor or anything, as the LED does not change when I try to wake up the machine.

- The output of `uname -a` is

  ```
  Linux rhubarbara 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- `/proc/acpi/wakeup` contains this, but I don't know what any of the 4 letter codes mean, and nothing there looks like the power button. I think it's just an issue with that, but I'm probably wrong.

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP1      S4    *disabled
GPP3      S4    *disabled
GPP4      S4    *disabled
GPP5      S4    *disabled
GPP6      S4    *disabled
GPP7      S4    *disabled
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
X161      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:08:00.0
GPP9      S4    *disabled
X162      S4    *disabled
GPPA      S4    *disabled
GPPB      S4    *disabled
GPPC      S4    *disabled
GPPD      S4    *disabled
GPPE      S4    *disabled
GPPF      S4    *disabled
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:09:00.3
GP18      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
UAR1      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:04
GPP2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.3
I211      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
X1_2      S4    *disabled
PTX4      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:05:00.0
X411      S4    *disabled
X413      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:07:00.0
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
```

Is there any way I could figure those out without trial and error? Or, if that's not necessary, what could the problem be?

Comment: ` I don't know what any of the 4 letter codes mean` add the output to the question and you can be sure someone will be able to tell you what they mean

Comment: there's also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250184/401568)

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, i did that. sorry, i'm new to this forum and stackoverflow in general